# Scrape webpage using jQuery and get JSON object

Tags: jquery, ajax

There is a page (from the same domain) that I'm trying to scrape to only get a JSON which is inside `<script>` tag with a specific `id`

```
<div id="someID">
    <script type="text/json" id="scriptID">
      {
        "some more here": "and there",
        "there are many more": "and the structure is various"
      }
    </script>
  <script>
    console.log("just another script which can be with or without id")
  </script>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use `ajax` call to get the page but couldn't query in to that specific tag with that ID yet.

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "/someurlhere.com/htmlpage.html",
   dataType: 'html',
   success: function (data) {
     console.log($(data).find("script").attr("id", "scriptID"));
   }
 });
```

When I log that the output when I do:

```
var newData = $(data).find("script").attr("id", "ceci-definition").text();
console.log(newData);
```

I'm seeing the content of the second script instead

```
    console.log("just another script which can be with or without id")
```

Comment: are you seeing an error? what's happening?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the most important part. When I do `that element.text()` I only see the second `<script>` return (those console.log(....)) instead of the one I need.

Comment: that is very important :) consider editing the question with this info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) aren't correct.

What you're doing is finding a `script` and setting its ID to `scriptID`.

Try this:

```
console.log($(data).find("script#scriptID").contents());
```

Basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/FbfE2/

Comment: :( I have tried that but the return jquery object is empty `context: undefined`

Comment: edited my answer. if this isn't helping, please consider setting up a jsfiddle to show us what's happening

Comment: I can see your jsfiddle is working fine there. :( Not sure why mine I can't. let me try make a fiddle quickly

Comment: it may also have to do with the fact there is a closing `</script>` in your HTML-- it may be prematurely ending your javascript. In fact, I'm pretty sure that's the problem. Consider wrapping it in some other kind of tag?

Comment: observe what happens when I comment the HTML out vs removing the comments (this version has comments in, take the comments out, re-run, and watch your console) http://jsfiddle.net/VstgL/1/